# how to store decision tree

Tags: python, python-2.7, decision-tree

I've tried several different methods, some of which I found on here which include making a Node class and nested dictionaries, but I can't seem to get them to work.

My code currently takes in several lines of DNA (a,t,g,c) and stores then as a numpy array.  It then finds the attribute that gives the most gain and splits the data into 4 new numpy arrays (dependent upon an a, t, g, or c being present at the attribute).

I'm unable to make a recursive function which can build the tree.  I'm quite new to python and programming itself, so please describe with detail what I should do.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983882/working-with-decision-trees?rq=1

Comment: could you give a more detailed example of how the logic would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to use a decision tree with python you can use the decision tree module from Sci-kit learn rather than write your own decision tree class and logic: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html. Using the Scikit Learn decision tree module you can save the decision tree objects to memory or perhaps write certain attributes of the tree to a file or database.

Sci-kit learn, as well as the other python libraries that are a part of the Anacondas package are pretty much the standard in data exploration and analysis in python. You can get the Anaconda package from Continuum here: http://continuum.io/downloads

**EDIT 1**

I came across this on Hacker News. It's about building a decision tree in Python using PostgreSQL as the database you pull values from. Might be interesting to checkout:
http://www.garysieling.com/blog/building-decision-tree-python-postgres-data

Comment: This is what I want, but I really would like to learn how to implement the decision tree myself.  I've asked some fellow programmers and they suggest using classes.  However, I'm still a bit oblivious as to how to implement a "class Node:" in order to get my desired outcome.

Comment: A great place to start is download the scikit learn source code and look at how they implement decision trees -- it's something I've done before with Numpy and matrix multiplication. You probably wont write code that is as fast or as optimized as scikit learns, but you'll understand how it's implemented.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to implement a decision tree from scratch I recommend you to build your tree using classes. A tree is composed of nodes, where one node contains nodes recursively and leafs are terminal nodes. For the case of a binary tree, these classes can be something like:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.split_variable = None
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

    def get_name(self):
        return 'Node'

class Leaf(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = None

    def get_name(self):
        return 'Leaf'
```

For the Node class: 'split_variable' will contain the variable name used in the split ie: [a,t,g,c] and 'left_child' and 'right_child' will be new instances of Node or Leaf. The True/False presence of that variable will be mapped into the left/right children. (In case of a regression tree you'll need to add a fourth variable to the Node class 'split_value' and map less/more than this value into the left/right children).

For the Leaf class: 'value' contains the assigned value of the tree class variable (ie majority in case of a discrete variable or mean in the case of a continuous one).

To complete your implementation you'll need functions to walk your tree evaluating and/or visualising it. These functions will be recursively called to complete walking through the tree. Here is where you can make use of the get_name() functions of the classes, to differentiate nodes from leafs. To implement this part it really depends on how you store your data, I suggest you to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) DataFrames which are like tables. A sample evaluate function could be (pseudocode):

```
def evaluate_tree(your_data, node):
    if your_data[node.split_variable]:
        if node.left_child.get_name() == 'Node':
            evaluate_tree(your_data, node.left_child)
        elif node.left_child.get_name() == 'Leaf':
            return node.left_child.value
    else:
        if node.right_child.get_name() == 'Node':
            evaluate_tree(your_data, node.right_child)
        elif node.right_child.get_name() == 'Leaf':
            return node.right_child.value
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

probably dict is what you want:

an example of node is:

```
{'sex': {'yes': 'send email', 'no': 'not send email'}}
```